# Apache .htaccess load subdirectory only if it exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current directory structure is `/www/<project>` which maps to `localhost/<project>`.  What I would like to do is load `localhost/<project>` with `/www/<project>/dist` ONLY if a dist directory exists in the project directory.  How can I do this with within .htaccess assuming rewrite is turned on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to test if a file or directory exists.

> You can perform various file attribute tests:
>
> '-d' (is directory)
>
> Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a directory.
>
> '-f' (is regular file)
>
> Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.